# Differences between Birur and הנהגה

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, halacha-theory, chazaka

How do the techniques of הנהגה and בירור work in Halacha? Is the difference that the latter needs proof, and the former is based  on a חזקה?

Comment: Where did you come across these terms?

Comment: @DoubleAA Famous from Qovets Shyurim from Rav Elchanan Vaserman